# Zammad - limit log level in production.log

Tags: logging

I found, that Zammad produces a huge log file: zammad-data/_data/log/production.log

This file collected 11GB over rarely 2 month. How can I controll the log level of this file? Can I redirect the output to docker log?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zammad core dev/maintainer here.

Usually I would recommend to use logrotate but since you are using docker there is an alternative: Our friend monotek just changed the docker (compose) image to log to STDOUT / docker log so you can handle it how you like. See: https://github.com/zammad/zammad-docker-compose/commit/d2cb86bd4b33a3c2ff2d498da2b76ed7ca87d8b5

EDIT: JFI you can ask technical questions over at http://community.zammad.org/ too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!